# Problems with mercurial encoding in command line

Tags: encoding, cmd, mercurial, tortoisehg

Today two things happened: (1) my mercurial repository's file called `00changelog.i` got corrupted and (2) mercurial stopped talking English all of a sudden inside cmd.

[image]

I have no idea how either (1) or (2) happened, but I gotta fix (2) first. I tried reinstalling/repairing/removing/installing.

By the way, the language pack on the system is non-English, but it worked just fine moments ago!

Please, help.

Comment: What's the encoding of the file?

Comment: This looks like Mercurial is using a localization with a non-Latin character set (Japanese, Chinese, or Russian in particular). This can be triggered by either by an environment variable (`LANGUAGE`, `LANG`, `LC_*`) or on Windows also by some system settings. You can try setting `LC_ALL=C` to see if this helps. If you can't figure it out, just removing the localized messages from your Mercurial installation should also function as a workaround (since it then will fall back to English).

Comment: @ReimerBehrends thanks, creating a LANGUAGE environment variable and setting it to en_US.UTF-8 solved the problem! Please, consider jotting down a little answer, so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial consults a number of sources for what localization information it should use for its messages (via the GNU gettext library and some Mercurial-specific plumbing): the environment variables `LANGUAGE`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_MESSAGES` (or other `LC_*` categories for non-message purposes), and `LANG`, in that order. On Windows, Mercurial will also consult `GetUserDefaultUILanguage()` as an alternative if none of the above environment variables are set.

Setting an environment variable from the above list to `C` is the easiest way to force Mercurial to use a specific language; Mercurial itself sets `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, and `LANGUAGE` to `C` for running its tests (similar to how autoconf configure scripts set `LC_ALL` and `LANGUAGE` to `C`).

Alternatively, it is also possible to remove localization files from your Mercurial installation entirely, though that should probably be used as a last resort.